# SQL How to split date interval in one or more intervals? depend of ExcludeIntervals table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DateIntervals(
ID uniqueidentifier primary key,
IdClient uniqueidentifier,
FromDate date,
ToDate date
)

CREATE TABLE ExcludeIntervals(
ID uniqueidentifier primary key,
IdDateIntervals  uniqueidentifier,
FromExcludedate date,
ToExcludeDate date
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExcludeIntervals]  ADD FOREIGN KEY([IdDateIntervals])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DateIntervals] ([ID])
GO

INSERT INTO  DateIntervals VALUES('9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '7F1468D0-AA7F-4F0E-9C1D-6FE8DE90E673', '2018-10-01','2019-09-01')
INSERT INTO  DateIntervals VALUES('10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317', '7F1468D0-AA7F-4F0E-9C1D-6FE8DE90E673', '2019-10-01','2020-04-01')
INSERT INTO  ExcludeIntervals VALUES('BB2899C5-8D6B-4DFB-93E8-DB9D3EF77E0C', '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-01-01','2019-01-10')
INSERT INTO  ExcludeIntervals VALUES('05C64864-5BCC-490D-AD97-B661E3D418C2', '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-04-15','2019-04-15')
INSERT INTO  ExcludeIntervals VALUES('22014263-CC36-4983-91D6-6AEA4DB2DFD7', '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-06-11','2019-07-02')
INSERT INTO  ExcludeIntervals VALUES('654D72F7-1C3A-4F74-A030-577601503105', '10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317', '2020-01-01','2020-01-10')
```

In "DateIntervals" I have the date intervals and in "ExcludeIntervals" are the periods that need to be excuded from "DateIntervals".
How I can split the intervals in order to excude the dates from the second table?

I need the fallowing output:

```
NEWID(), '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2018-10-01','2018-12-31'

NEWID(), '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-01-11','2019-04-14'

NEWID(), '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-04-16','2019-06-10

NEWID(), '9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379', '2019-07-03','2019-09-01'
```

and

```
NEWID(), '10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317', '2019-10-01','2019-12-31'

NEWID(), '10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317', '2020-01-11','2020-04-01'
```

Any help is appreciated
THX

Comment: Would you be able to share sample input data? It’s hard to understand just by looking at the output data without input dataset. Also, please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach generates the date interval using the [tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) tvf fnNumbers.  Then the date ranges to be excluded are removed using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` against similarly expanded (exclusion) intervals.  Then using `CASE WHEN` and the `DATEDIFF` of the calculated date and its `LAG`, summary groups of contiguous date ranges are identified.  Then the query summarizes by ID using the summary groups and the `MIN` and `MAX` functions are applied to the (remaining) calculated dates.  Something like this

tally tvf fnNumbers

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

Query

```
with 
d_int_cte(id, dt) as (
    select d.ID, dateadd(day, fn.n, d.FromDate)
    from #DateIntervals d
         cross apply fnNumbers(0, datediff(day, d.FromDate, d.ToDate)) fn),
ex_int_cte(id, dt, lag_dt_diff_ind) as (
    select di.id, di.dt, 
           case when datediff(day, lag(di.dt) over (order by di.dt), di.dt)>1 then 1 else 0 end
    from d_int_cte di
    where not exists(select 1
                     from #ExcludeIntervals e
                          cross apply fnNumbers(0, datediff(day, e.FromExcludedate, e.ToExcludeDate)) fn_in
                          cross apply (select dateadd(day, fn_in.n, e.FromExcludedate) dt) da
                     where di.dt=da.dt)),
sum_grp_cte(id, dt, sum_grp) as (
    select ei.id, ei.dt,
           sum(lag_dt_diff_ind) over (order by ei.dt) sum_grp
    from ex_int_cte ei)
select newid() new_guid, sg.id, min(sg.dt) FromDate, max(sg.dt) ToDate
from sum_grp_cte sg
group by sg.id, sg.sum_grp
order by 2 desc, 3;
```

Output

```
new_guid                                id                                      FromDate    ToDate
0B25828E-BBAB-4414-B5E8-9B72A929DC7D    9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379    2018-10-01  2018-12-31
0DFA9975-A3CA-497E-9F58-D3FCD5FCE49F    9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379    2019-01-11  2019-04-14
DDE59CC7-1A14-4FE9-BDA2-CB3AE50982DD    9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379    2019-04-16  2019-06-10
474F3BB9-5A65-4685-9CEF-6589342B7A48    9DA7B153-30EF-4684-9321-94223F19B379    2019-07-03  2019-09-01
710DC8FA-EC14-4F6A-B91D-4264804EFE31    10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317    2019-10-01  2019-12-31
A10CCE86-DE63-4B58-82B0-36AC73F0FCD5    10F7461C-1D59-4F8E-8FA4-5DD726EF4317    2020-01-11  2020-04-01
```